# Is it possible to use DBMS_SQLHASH.GETHASH with bind variables?

Tags: oracle, plsql

In Oracle, **DBMS_SQLHASH.GETHASH** is a good way to return a hash of a query rather than rolling your own hash code. We've been using it for a while now and everything has been fine, like so:

```
SELECT DBMS_SQLHASH.GETHASH(q'[SELECT * FROM SCOTT.EMP ORDER BY 1]', 1) FROM DUAL;
```

But now we're running across cases where we need to pass bind variables into the string that's executed and I can't figure out a way to do that.

Effectively we're trying to do this:

```
SELECT DBMS_SQLHASH.GETHASH(q'[SELECT * FROM SCOTT.EMP WHERE JOB = 'CLERK' ORDER BY 1]', 1) FROM DUAL;
```

Which obviously works, but doesn't use bind variables, and is a bit ugly.

My thought was to use dynamic SQL to bind the variable:

```
DECLARE
  vResult VARCHAR2(4000);
  vRole VARCHAR2(5) := 'CLERK';
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
    'SELECT DBMS_SQLHASH.GETHASH(''SELECT * FROM SCOTT.EMP WHERE JOB = :Role ORDER BY 1'', 1) FROM DUAL'
    INTO vResult
   USING vRole;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(vResult);
END;
/
```

But this returns **ORA-01006: bind variable does not exist**, presumably because the bind variable within the execute immediate string is also inside a string.

I've seen some suggestion that it may be possible to use **DBMS_SQL** to execute the query the way I want but my experiments along those lines have led to the same results.

Is it possible to pass in bind variables in this fashion, or am I doomed to re-write the queries without them?

Thanks!

Comment: The procedure `GETHASH` receives parameter `sqltext`, so I assume internally a dynamic cursor will be opened with `OPEN v_cursor FOR sqltext`. To pass in bind variables the parameter `USING` would have to be used. So I guess the is no  legal chance to pass in BVs.

Answer (score 0):

In this case literal concatenation is the right solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_hash( p_job IN VARCHAR2 )
IS
   vResult      VARCHAR2( 4000 );
   v_statement  VARCHAR2( 500 )
      := q'[SELECT DBMS_SQLHASH.GETHASH('SELECT * FROM HR.EMPLOYEES WHERE JOB_ID = '']' || p_job || q'['' ORDER BY 1', 1) FROM DUAL]';
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( v_statement );

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_statement INTO vResult;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( vResult );
END;
/

DECLARE
   vRole  VARCHAR2( 12 ) := 'PU_CLERK';
BEGIN
   my_hash( vRole );
END;
/
```

I reworked your example for the HR scheme. Notice that even in the q'[]' notation double quotes are needed, because of the two-level parsing. This also prevents SQL-Injection, as the Parameter will allways be interpreted as a text value.